# How to change a page location after inactivity of 5 mins

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I want that if there is no activity on my page for 5 mins then the page will be redirected to a predefined page.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: A suggestion: do a sleep (`timeout` in JS ductus) and then redirect…

Answer (score 8):

If you want a real inactivity control please use this library (which control **mouse** and **keyboard** activity too)

***The jQuery idletimer***

http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/

Here is an example use of it:

```
// idleTimer() takes an optional argument that defines the idle timeout
// timeout is in milliseconds; defaults to 30000
$.idleTimer(10000);


$(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){
 // function you want to fire when the user goes idle
});


$(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function(){
 // function you want to fire when the user becomes active again
});

// pass the string 'destroy' to stop the timer
$.idleTimer('destroy');
```

Answer (score 6):

Something similar to this maybe?

```
<body onmousemove="canceltimer()" onclick="canceltimer()">

<script type="text/javascript">

var tim = 0;
function reload() {
tim = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",300000);   // 5 minutes
}

function canceltimer() {
window.clearTimeout(tim);  // cancel the timer on each mousemove/click
reload();  // and restart it
}

</script>
```

Comment: why you guys always use string in `setTimeout`? :(

Comment: keyup or something like that also needed (I can work with keyboard only)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this blog article regarding detecting idle users in web sites. It is an [jQuery Idletimer Plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/). And you can find the [demo page here](http://paulirish.com/demo/idle-timer).

Simple usage:

```
// idleTimer() takes an optional argument that defines the idle timeout
// timeout is in milliseconds; defaults to 30000
$.idleTimer(10000);
```

And you get the source from [github](http://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer/) for [jQuery Idletimer Plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/)

Answer (score -3):

Couldn't you just set the META Refresh to the number of seconds you want for the timeout and point to the appropriate redirect page?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="60;url=http://www.mydomain.com/redirect_page.html">
```

I know this is generally frowned upon, but it avoids the need for jQuery (or Javascript, for that matter) and all browsers honor it.

Sometimes simple is better, even if it is ugly.

Comment: This doesn't work at all.  The original question asked for idleness detection.  In this case it will refresh whether or not the user has been idle.